# PHP: receive POST data progressively (arduino esp8266 car gps tracker project)

Tags: php, post, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I found this nice example on building a gps-sd-wifi project.

[MartijnBraam/car-tracker](https://github.com/MartijnBraam/car-tracker/blob/master/GPS.ino)

The problem is in github the php file is not included.

How should I read the data coming from an ESP8266 (or equivalent) using this code as the sender...

I would like to get all the data and be able to save it to a file, or redirect it to mysql.

Thank you

```
void uploadTrack(char* name){
  File log = SD.open(name);
  WiFiClient client;
  int tracker = ESP.getChipId();
  String trackerId = String(tracker);
  Serial.printf("Uploading %s\n", name);
  if(client.connect("tracker.brixit.nl", 80)){
    Serial.println("Sending headers");
    String length = String(log.size());
    String headers = String("POST /upload.php HTTP/1.0\r\n")+
      "Host: tracker.brixit.nl\r\n" +
      "Connection: close\r\n" + 
      "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n" + 
      "Content-Length: " + length + "\r\n" +
      "X-Tracker: " + trackerId + "\r\n" +
      "X-Secret: " + secret + "\r\n" + 
      "X-Track: " + name + "\r\n" +
      "\r\n";
    client.print(headers);
    Serial.println("Sending data");

    char buffer[1470];
    while(true){
      int bytes = log.read(buffer,1470);
      if(bytes < 1){
        break;
      }
      client.write_P(buffer, bytes);
      delay(0);
    }
    Serial.println("Upload done");
    client.stop();
  }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by progressively? Usually PHP has a ‘max_execution_time’ which is 30 seconds by default. Even though this of course can be changed I think it might be better to collect some data on the client, and send that data in chunks over multiple requests.

Comment: The 'progressive' part is the while loop you can see in the code. Maybe 'progressive' is not the correct word to describe it. But basically the question is, how to code a PHP to receive the data coming from the code above

Comment: Thats exactly my point. The connection is opened before starting the `while` loop, that is then consistently sending data and after the `while` loop the connection is closed. When this will exit is unknown as it will continue to send (in the same POST connection) as long as data is coming. Otherwise that looks to me like a standard POST request, the same as handling form input with PHP. Could be any other language as well as long as HTTP requests can be handled.

Comment: Thanks waza-ari, I just managed to make it work half an hour ago. I will post my working code tonight. Thanks for trying to help.